# Attempting to save username from twitter user to Firebase database iOS app

Tags: swift, firebase, twitter, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to save a twitter users username into the database for later reference my code below is executing but doesn't seem to be accessing the database or saving the username into the database and I'm really lost as to why. I'm attempting to have the username and userID so I can retrieve information about the user for a profile page in the app. So if I can avoid saving this data to the database all together that works too but I don't think it can be done that way.

```
fileprivate func setupTwitterButton() {
    let twitterButton = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to login via Twitter: ", err)
            return
        }

        // debug statement
        //print("Successfully logged in using Twitter")

        HUD.show(.labeledProgress(title: nil, subtitle: "Signing In"))
        //we've authenticated twitter, time to log into firebase

        guard let token = session?.authToken else { return }
        guard let secret = session?.authTokenSecret else { return }
        let creds = FIRTwitterAuthProvider.credential(withToken: token, secret: secret)
        let dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let usersref = dbref.child("users")



        let uid = session?.userID

        //let user = FIRAuth.auth?.signIn

        print("Creating user")

        let newUserReference = usersref.child(uid!)
        newUserReference.setValue(["username": session?.userName])
```

Comment: Does `session?.userName` have a value? Do you see "creating user" in your Xcode's debug area? How about the rules of your database, have you checked it and see if you can write anything?

Comment: I've done some more testing and it seems t to have the value  there and I'm seeing 'creating user' in the debug area. I'm actually getting a permissions error from firebase. I thought this wouldn't be the case as i already logged in at the top. Plus the rest of the application can write to the database just fine. Clearly I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after some debugging it was pretty simple where I went wrong. I was trying to write to the database before I'd authenticated with the database. Once I had put my code for writing to the database after I'd authenticated it all worked correctly.